# How do I create a function for separating parts of a function?

Tags: matlab

I want to enter a function **f(x,y(x))** with the general form **f(x,y(x)) = g(x) + w(x)y** in MatLab. Then, I want to separate the g and w functions, but still having them in terms of x.

I used the following code:

```
function [G,W] = create_fxy(f)
    syms x
    y=inline(f);
    G_1=y(x,0);
    syms  y
    W_1=diff(f,y,1);
    W=inline(W_1)
    G=inline(G_1);
end
```

It works pretty good, but when I'm trying to enter functions like: $sen(x) + cos(x)y$, it shows me the following error

```
Error using inlineeval (line 14)
Error in inline expression ==> sen(x) + cos(x)*y
 Undefined function 'sen' for input arguments of type 'sym'.
```

Error in inline/subsref (line 23)
    INLINE_OUT_ = inlineeval(INLINE_INPUTS_, INLINE_OBJ_.inputExpr, INLINE_OBJ_.expr);

Error in create_fxy (line 4)
    G_1=y(x,0);

What could I do?

Comment: Do you mean sin instead of sen?

Comment: You need to define the function `sen`.  That is if you didn't mean `sin`...  The error message tells you all you need to know.

Comment: @Matt Thank you. I didn't realize my error. I'm a spanish speaker so I'm used to write `sen` from (seno) instead of `sin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in the command the correct function is `sin` instead of `sen`.